# Calls to supertype methods in traits allowed with `extends` but not with self-types

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits, self-type

Consider:

```
trait SuperBar { def superBarMethod = ??? }
trait Bar extends SuperBar

trait FooWithSelfType { this: Bar =>
  super.superBarMethod // error: value superBarMethod is not a member of AnyRef
}

trait FooWithExtends extends Bar {
  super.superBarMethod
}
```

Is this limitation due to some underlying implementation shortcoming, or it's actually designed this way for a reason?

The way I see this is that if `this` is known to be of type `Bar`, and `Bar` is known to be a subtype of `SuperBar`, then invoking any `SuperBar` methods on `this` should be allowed.

Comment: Why do you need to qualify the call to `superBarMethod` with `super.`.  It's available already without needing to use `super.` as you have declared yourself as requiring `Bar` to be available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FooWithSelfType` might *know* that it is a `Bar`, but it's not actually part of `FooWithSelfType`'s inheritance hierarchy, so it doesn't have access to `super` except for the `super` that is explicitly part of its inheritance hierarchy.  If you had

```
trait Baz extends SuperBaz { this : Bar => 
  /* ... */
}
```

how would you know to what `super` refers if both `SuperBaz` and `SuperBar` were possibilities?

Comment: Couldn't the same "how would you know ..." question be asked about `trait Baz extends SuperBaz with Bar { super.superBarMethod }` then? And this is an entirely legal construction. ...in other words: if `super` works in the case of `extends SuperBaz with Bar`, it could also work in the case of `extends SuperBaz { this: Bar =>`, in my opinion... not sure tho how much effort that would be in the compiler.

Comment: P.S. without doubt there's a technical explanation as to why the compiler currently refuses to accept this, but I'd like to know if there's a more fundamental reason the compiler couldn't (be made to) handle this "as expected".

Comment: @ErikAllik - There are linearization rules, and you can get the linearization you want by reordering the list of traits.  You can't reorder those with respect to the self-type annotation, though.  Not to mention that linearization is complicated enough already.

Comment: OK, even though I'm not able to wrap my head around it yet, I'm trusting your competence.

Comment: @ErikAllik - Briefly, `class Qux extends Foo with Bar with Baz` has `Baz` as its immediate super-type.  `class Qux extends Baz with Foo with Bar` has `Bar` as its immediate super-type.  That's fiddly enough without having to worry about how self-types interact.

Answer (score 2):

Self-type says that the current trait should be mixed into is at most the type you are using as a self-type. Meaning that all subtypes of that given type can mix the current trait. With that in mind, super only refers to the class/trait that the current trait is a sub class/trait of.

I have to say that I ran into this thought not that long ago, and I think this could be a weakness, I mean we could imagine that the compiler could look up both methods in the superclass and those in the self-type's superclass.

Comment: in other words, the way I see this, is that it's a limitation of how `super` is defined, not a mathematical limitation... ?

Comment: That's what I've been thinking too. This is only my humble opinion.